# Why smiley disabling REGEXP causes editing of text impossible?

Tags: jquery, regex

I have used the following `RegExp` to disable smileys in a textbox. It was working fine.

```
title = title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/'"\[\]]+/g,'');
```

But when I did this, I got an issue. If I try to edit a text in that textbox, the cursor will go to the end of text.

Let's say "How are you?" is the text entered in the textbox. If I try to add 'old' in between 'how' and 'are', the cursor will go the end of text.

```
jQuery('#topic_title').bind('input propertychange', function(e) {
    title = jQuery("#topic_title").val(); 
    title = title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/'"\[\]]+/g,'');
    jQuery("#topic_title").val(title); });
```

When I removed the RegExp, editing is possible. I hope the issue is related to the RegExp. Please help me to find a solution.

Comment: can you provide the full code i.e when this regex is being triggered

Comment: jQuery('#topic_title').bind('input propertychange', function(e) {title = jQuery("#topic_title").val();
                //title = title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/'"\[\]]+/g,'');
                jQuery("#topic_title").val(title);
}); Here is the full code that i am using.

Comment: @NithinkumarCN - Please *edit* your question and put that code in there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because replacing is being done after every change (each key press).
You can replace `bind('input propertychange'` with `bind('blur'`. This will remove smileys after focus is lost from input box.

Or you need to store cursor position before replacing the text and then set the cursor to original position.
Here is an example how to do it

```
jQuery('#topic_title').bind('input propertychange', function(e) {
    title = jQuery("#topic_title").val(); 
    var caretPosition = getCaret(this);
    title = title.replace(/[^a-zA-Z 0-9.~`!@#$%^&*()_+-={}|:;<>,.?\/'"\[\]]+/g,'');
    jQuery("#topic_title").val(title); 
    setCaretToPos(this, caretPosition);     
});

function getCaret(node) {
  if (node.selectionStart) {
    return node.selectionStart;
  } else if (!document.selection) {
    return 0;
  }

  var c = "\001",
  sel = document.selection.createRange(),
  dul = sel.duplicate(),
  len = 0;

  dul.moveToElementText(node);
  sel.text = c;
  len = dul.text.indexOf(c);
  sel.moveStart('character',-1);
  sel.text = "";
  return len;
}

function setSelectionRange(input, selectionStart, selectionEnd) {
    if (input.setSelectionRange) {
      input.focus();
    input.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd);
  }
  else if (input.createTextRange) {
    var range = input.createTextRange();
    range.collapse(true);
    range.moveEnd('character', selectionEnd);
    range.moveStart('character', selectionStart);
    range.select();
  }
}

function setCaretToPos (input, pos) {
  setSelectionRange(input, pos, pos);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/11c1z774/